# How can a CAPTCHA be integrated into a community?

Tags: captcha

I'm planning on making a **simple discussion feature** for a web framework I'm building. 
It should:

- allow anonymous posting
- block spam bots

The obvious answer is to use a generic "**captcha**" plugin, however I think there are some **creative opportunities** here that I would like to explore, e.g. questions like:

- (simple math) what is four + three? ***_***
- (pop culture) who sings like a virgin? ***_***
- (history) last name of first U.S. president: ***_*__**
- (pictures) [picture of Obama], who is this?: ***_*___**
- (contextual) what year was our association founded? ***_*__**
- (company) last name of our personnel director: ***_*___**
- (current events) the country that toppled Muburak: ***_***

The captcha could actually be used to **teach people about the community**, information that they had to look up, etc.

Or these could be **collected from users** of the community, the ones which got approved and used would earn them reputation points.

**What is the best way for a CAPTCHA to be designed so that it not only blocks spammers but helps reflect the knowledge of a community?**

Comment: Please check the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective) blog post to learn what makes a good question. This is simply a "list of X" type question. If it could be rephrased then it might make a good question.

Comment: that link is broken

Comment: Assuming you mean the blog link - I've just tried it and it works OK for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation of the following, at a site of a research institute.
[image]

*Rather simple actually, when you think about it, but guaranteed to scare off most.*

Comment: And what is the answer? :)

Comment: @Sebastien Le Callonnec - Now that would be telling ;)

Comment: @Sebastien I think it is 0

Comment: @Gaurav - Yes. [obligatory remaining characters]